# in Python, Results from a DLNA call are not parsed into a list. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, dlna

No error is shown, but the list of album titles isn't either. Here's the code excerpt from the Python program. Content_directory_url = http://mediaserverlocationUniqueID/upnp.org-ContentDirectory-1/control.
ObjectID contains the search criteria in for the SOAPAction #Browse command.

```
`headers = {
    "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "SOAPAction": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ContentDirectory:1#Browse"
}      

ObjectID = "0$albums"

  soap_payload = f"""
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> 
        <s:Body> 
            <u:Browse xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ContentDirectory:1"> 
            <ObjectID>{ObjectID}</ObjectID> 
            <BrowseFlag>BrowseDirectChildren</BrowseFlag> 
            <Filter>*</Filter> 
            <StartingIndex>0</StartingIndex> 
            <RequestedCount>0</RequestedCount> 
            <SortCriteria></SortCriteria> 
            </u:Browse> 
        </s:Body> 
    </s:Envelope>
"""   

try:
    response = requests.post(content_directory_url, headers=headers, data=soap_payload)
    response.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
    SystemExit

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Results")
    print ("")
    root = ET.fromstring(response.text)
    for child in root.iter("*"):
        print(child.tag, f"Child value:", child.text)

    namespace = {"dlna": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/DIDL-Lite",
                 "upnp": "urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/upnp/"}
```

Music_items should contain a list of albums based on the ObjectID search criteria but it returns no values.**

```
    music_items = root.findall(".//dlna:container[dlna:class=object.item]", namespace)
   
    for music_folder in music_items:
        music_folder_name = music_folder.findall(".//dlna:title", namespace).text
        print(f"Audio Name: {music_folder_name}")

else:
    print("Error: Could not retrieve folders from DLNA server: ", response.status_code)`
```